# Transparent background of <div> CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

For those who can't wait [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnsemblante/ouy9thkk/)

I have this problem in CSS. The structure of the `html` and `css` code looks like this

HTML:

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.one{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: url('http://www.moonlightcompanies.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/6973_MOONF-PomegranatesOnTree-8536-1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 20px;
}

.two{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
    padding: 20px;
}

.three{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

My problem is how do I make the background of `<div class="three"></div>` that it would be transparent and would blend to the background of the `<div class="one"></div>`. I want my desired output to be like the attached image. Is this possible ?

[image]

Comment: The background is transparent but it transparent to its parent, and the background color of its parent is - blue. Consider "switching" the divs, the `second` div would be the transparent one and the `third` div would be the blue background one.

Comment: background of three is transparent but two is not transparent.

Comment: This is related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485098/css-transparent-border-showing-the-behind-background-image

Comment: May I ask why you didn't you use a [stack snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to post your code? You even divided the html from css, it's really a matter of seconds to integrate this. Consider this instead of using an external service like jsfiddle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ouy9thkk/2/)**

```
.three{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 5px solid yellow;
    outline:solid 100px rgba(0,0,255,.5);
}
```

update the border value as per your requirement.

Updated **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ouy9thkk/10/)**

```
.three {
    background: transparent;
    border: solid blue;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    border-width:20px 40px 40px 20px;
}
.inner {
    outline: 5px solid yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    margin:0;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This works great Sir :) I have another question. I've updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/johnsemblante/ouy9thkk/5/ what if I have that kind of structure ? how will I do such Sir ? :) Anyway thanks a lot for the answer got some idea but have still hanging questions on my mind :) Thank you in advance Sir.

Comment: Maybe it also help you: [basics-css-blend-modes](https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/) and to check browser compatibility [can I use blend mode](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode)

Comment: Good use of outline +1! You could probably mention that box-shadow can have the same output and offer more control on the width of the blue part on all four sides.

Answer (score 4):

I have added `:before` and `:after` also for blue background in right and bottom, so that more content can be added in the second `div`.

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/ouy9thkk/15/

Answer (score 3):

As per your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ouy9thkk/14/

I have used box shadow to achieve the expected result.

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one{
    width: 800px;
    height:800px;
    background: url('http://www.moonlightcompanies.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/6973_MOONF-PomegranatesOnTree-8536-1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 20px;
}

.two{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.three{
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    border: 5px solid yellow;
    box-shadow: 10px 0px 0 30px blue
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/ouy9thkk/16/)

```
.one{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: url('http://www.moonlightcompanies.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/6973_MOONF-PomegranatesOnTree-8536-1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 20px;    
}
.blue{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue; 
    border-width: 20px 115px 65px 20px;
}
.yellow{
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    border: 5px solid yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Closest I could get with this particular case:

```
.two{
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
background: trasparent;
padding: 0px;
border-top: 20px solid blue;
border-right: 60px solid blue;
border-bottom: 60px solid blue;
border-left: 20px solid blue;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ouy9thkk/3/)**

Comment: This works too Sir :) I have another question. I've updated my fiddle jsfiddle.net/johnsemblante/ouy9thkk/5 what if I have that kind of structure ? how will I do such Sir ? :) Anyway thanks for the answer :) Thank you in advance Sir.

Answer (score -1):

try this example:(

```
jsfiddle.net/MxspA/6/
```

)
please use rectangle image which should transparent from center like following example

jsfiddle.net/MxspA/6/